# For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, is there a unitary matrix $V$ s.t. every minor of $V$ is nonzero?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following statement true?

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a unitary $V\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ s.t. every minor of $V$ is nonzero.

I need this statement to prove a result in my research. By [Chebotarev's theorem on roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev_theorem_on_roots_of_unity), it's true for prime $n$, but I need it to be true for all $n$.

I've thought of a few possible constructions, the most promising so far is taking an $n\times n$ [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) with $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ as the first $n$ primes, then using the Gram-Schmidt process to orthonormalize the columns.  However, I have no idea how to go about proving that every minor of such a matrix is non-zero.

Comment: Have you tried the complex Hadamard matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Consider $U(n)$ with its Haar measure. The condition that any particular minor is zero
defines a measure zero subset of $U(n)$, so the set of matrices in $U(n)$ with some
particular minor being zero has measure zero, and so isn't all of $U(n)$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Your answer sounds promising, but can you expand it some (or do you know of a resource containing a proof of your statement)?  The only exposure I've had to the concept of a measure is from a class that used the Royden-Fitzpatrick functional analysis book, and it's been a few years.

Answer (score 0):

The Grover diffusion operator - the householder matrix that rotates a vector about its mean has all elements non-zero. For a unitary matrix D of dimension $n\times n$ the elements are $$D[i,j]=\begin{cases} \frac2n−1 &, i=j \\ \frac2n & , i \ne j\end{cases}  $$